# Joint PDF of Gamma Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

Let $W_r$ denotes time taken for the r-th occurrence of the phenomenon in Poisson process $\{N_t : t \ge 0\}$ with occurrence rate $\lambda$

$$W_r = \min\{t:N_t \ge r\},\; r= 1,2,3..$$

Here I want to derive joint pdf of $X = W_2/W_4, Y = W_4/W_5$.

First for the random variable $X= W_2/W_4,$ since $W_2 \thicksim Gamma(2, 1/\lambda)$ and $W_4 \thicksim Gamma(4, 1/\lambda)$, $f(w_2)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(2)(1/\lambda)^4}x\cdot e^{-\lambda x}I(x>0)$ and $f(w_4)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(4)(1/\lambda)^4}x\cdot e^{-\lambda x}I(x>0)$.

Then $f(X=W_2/W_4) = \dfrac{\Gamma(4)}{\Gamma(2)}\cdot\lambda^2=6\lambda^2$

But though I had derived pdf of $X$,when I integrate it through $0$ to $\infty$ it doesn't result in $1$ and I think there I had done some wrong.

Any hint or advice to approach this problem correctly?

Comment: This does not make much sense: first, you need to review what the Gamma(4,lambda) PDF is, second, since when is the PDF of a ratio the ratio of the PDFs, third, how computing a marginal would yield a joint distribution, one wonders.

Comment: The standard approach is to compute the joint PDF of $$(W_2,W_4,W_5)$$ say, then to deduce the joint PDF of $$(W_2,X,Y)$$ using the change of variables formula, and finally to deduce the joint PDF of $$(X,Y)$$ by marginalization. Which step is a problem?

Comment: I can't understand how can I deduce the joint PDF of $(W_2, X, Y)$ from $(W_2, W_4, W_5)$

Comment: Quote: "using the change of variables formula". Sorry but this is really the basics of the field, so one can wonder what you have been taught to tackle this kind of question...

Comment: Sorry for my inability to solve the basics.. I have a question from the baic again. Does pdf (w2, w4, w5) equal to pdf(w2, w4-w2, w5-w4)=pdf(w2)pdf(w4-w2)pdf(w5-w4)?